# Angular Data URLs processing

Tags: css, angular, svg

I use the `flag-icon-css` library and for some flags the size is not correct due to the `background-image` property which is interpreted differently. I did not manage to create a Stackblitz so here is the minimal step to reproduce:

```
ng new bug-so
cd bug-so
npm install flag-icon-css
```

In angular.json, I added the CSS:

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css"
        ],
```

In app.component.html

```
<div style="padding: 5em">
  <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-es" style="border: 1px solid black"></span><br/>
  <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr" style="border: 1px solid black"></span><br/>
</div>
```

Run the app

```
ng serve
```

The spanish flag is interpreted as:

```
.flag-icon-es {
    background-image: url(es.svg);
}
```

whereas the french flag is interpreted as:

```
.flag-icon-fr {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%2…830%22 d%3D%22M426.662 0H640v480H426.662z%22%2F%3E %3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
}
```

If the background-image is a Data URL, the display is correct. I tried without angular and the styles are the one from the original CSS file and both flags are displayed correctly:

```
.flag-icon-fr {
    background-image: url(../flags/4x3/fr.svg);
}

.flag-icon-es {
    background-image: url(../flags/4x3/es.svg);
}
```

With Angular
[image: With Angular]

Without Angular
[image: Without Angular]

Comment: for some reason when i went to the `node_modules\flag-icon-css\flags\1x1` folder and deleted the `es.svg` file and copied another file renamed it to `es.svg` the issue resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know why but angular serve from the folder `node_modules\flag-icon-css\flags\1x1` and not the correct `node_modules\flag-icon-css\flags\4x3`

for why the second image is correct but loaded with strange way

that's because the second one is less than 10kb so it will be embedded not served separately (and for some reason angular embed the correct image)

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#css-resources

i think you should open an issue in the angular github repo

Comment: For tracking the issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12186

Comment: I hope they fix it soon, do you need a work around till they do?

Comment: The project is in development for the moment. I think I can copy the correct flag from 4x3 to 1x1 folder since I am using  only the 4x3 flags.

Comment: i think it will be better to copy the css file to your `assets` and exchange all 1x1 reference to 4x3 one, with correcting the path to use the `node_modules` one, you will need to do find and replace but i don't think its a hard job